# AngularJS multiple elements with same callback ng-click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-click

I have multiple elements that display an icon with a its' respective label. Upon click of any of the icons, I would like to display the next step. I can simply attach the ng-click event handler to EACH of the DOM elements for the function to trigger. I'd like to find a 'cleaner' way where I can have one "ng-click" that would apply to each of the elements( 8 in total). I'm a newbie to angularJS and have not been able to find an alternative to do so. Thanks!

```
<ul class="list-inline row">
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="col-sm-6" ng-click="displayStep2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span>
                        <p>Cutlery &#38; Service</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>
                        <p>AV Equipment</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="col-sm-6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
                        <p>Furniture &#38; Fixtures</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                        <p>Supplies</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="col-sm-6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></span>
                        <p>Transportation</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span>
                        <p>Set Up &#38; Clean Up</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="col-sm-6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                        <p>Shipment Tracking</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>
                        <p>Temperature</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

<script>
    $scope.displayStep2 = function(){
        window.location.href = "/requestPortal/meeting/2/request/create";
    }; 
</scirpt>
```

Comment: The "Angular" way of doing this would be storing this data in an array and then using `ng-repeat` to template it out.

Comment: is it feasible even if each label has a different icon associated with it? I am using the gylphicons from twitter bootstrap?

Comment: Of course - you can use `ng-class` based on a property value

Comment: (lightbulb flickered) +1

Comment: after I loop thru the items in my array...I would still need to list out the 8 different glyphicons correct? then assign the property name to each one?

Comment: Yeah, so imagine you have an array of objects - those objects could have a property such as `className: "sort"` - then you could so `class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{item.className}}"`